# remove content inside different parentheses with php

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know how I could remove the text between a set of parentheses and the parentheses themselves with regexp in php, the paretheses could be different... for example:

[mycontent}

or

(mycontent]

or

{mycontent)

and so on...

I have tried:

```
preg_replace("/\{.*\}/", " ", $title);
preg_replace("/\[.*\]/", " ", $title);
preg_replace("/\(.*\)/", " ", $title);
```

but this just remove the same parentheses.. and yes parentheses could be nested till the second grade..

Comment: Can these parentheses be nested?  e.g. How would you handle "[my (content} here)"?

Comment: I edited my question with the code I have tried

Answer (score 1):

You need to set charsets using `[]` and hold charsets using `()`;

```
print preg_replace("~([\[\{\(]).*?([\]\}\)])~", "\\1...\\2", 
        "[mycontent} a (mycontent] b {mycontent)");
```

Outputs: `[...} a (...] b {...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = "[mycontent}outside(mycontent]outside{mycontent)";

$find = array(
    "/\{.*?\}/",
    "/\{.*?\]/",
    "/\{.*?\)/",
    "/\[.*?\}/",
    "/\[.*?\]/",
    "/\[.*?\)/",
    "/\(.*?\}/",
    "/\(.*?\]/",
    "/\(.*?\)/"
);
$replace = array(
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " "
);
$string = preg_replace($find, $replace, $title);

var_dump($string); // prints string(17) " outside outside "
```